# Is it possible to reinitialize a git repo without deleting the local files?

Tags: git, github, initialization, repository

I always get this `error: pack-objects died of signal 9` error when I pull from my repo.
I already tried all the commands I could find on Stackoverflow and the internet, none of them solved my issue, but what I read was that it might work again if I reintialize the git repo by deleting the `.git` folder.

How do I reinitialize the git repo with keeping the local files (because there are some files and folders that are not in git and I want to keep them). What I tried already is to add my remote after doing `git init`. But it doesn't recognize the local files, it shows them as "changes".

Comment: signal 9 is the forced-immediate-kill signal pretty much everywhere that has signals, I don't know of any exception to that convention. Git never does this. Only way I can think it happens sorta-automatically is if your repo's hosted on a system too small for it and it's driving the OS to invoking the OOM killer, the out-of-memory killer that tries to prevent the entire system from completely wedging by killing processes until the memory emergency goes away.

Comment: I could fix it!!! I just cloned the same repo and copied the .git folder from there (and deleted the old one .git)